# Add parameter to Datatable function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, datagridview

I want to display procedure result in DataGridView and Get parameter value from Combobox

I have created a SQL procedure named `Report_with_depo`

```
Create proc [dbo].[Report_with_depo]
@customer_id nvarchar (50)

AS
select customer_id ,customer_fullname, amount_withdraw ,amount_deposit ,entry_date
from Oprations b 
inner join Customers a
    on b.customer_id2 = a.customer_id
where customer_id = @customer_id
```

and Datatable function

```
public DataTable Report_with_depo()
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DAL.SelectData("Report_with_depo", null);
    return dt;
}
```

and the Display button code was like

```
this.dgv_Report.DataSource = Report_con.Report_with_depo();
```

I have tested my code and replace the parameter with a value it worked, but now I want to get the value from the Combobox

Comment: yes it worked fine but before i have added a parameter to the procedure after parameter have been added i did not know how to add it to data table and get the value for the parameter from combobox

Comment: Well what does `DAL.SelectData` do? And why would you use such a generic function, why not have a proper function for each procedure with its parameters?

Comment: DAL is DataAccessLayer Folder it contain all requirement for database connection , Select Data  // To read from DB
 public DataTable SelectData(string stored_prc, SqlParameter[] param)
 {
     cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = stored_prc;
     cmd.Connection = con;
     if (param != null)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
         {
             cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
         }
     }
     da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);
     return dt;
 }

Comment: So what's your problem, just do `DAL.SelectData("Report_with_depo", new[]{ new SqlParameter("@customer_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Value = someValueHere } ) })`  Side note: you need to dispose the connection, command and adapter, do *not* cache the connection object.

Comment: fine it solved my issue thanks alot